# Chaning tcp_keepalive_* inside a docker container

Tags: docker, proc

I have an application running inside a docker container, and I want to set: `tcp_keepalive_intvl` and `tcp_keepalive_time`.

Can I just change it on the host system and expect docker (and eveything inside) to honor these settings?

Because `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_keepalive_*` do not exist inside the container.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to look into Docker run documentation to override with `--sysctl net.ipv4.xxx` in `docker run` command. Please note that `--sysctl` does not work with `docker service` command...

Details please refer to https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#configure-namespaced-kernel-parameters-sysctls-at-runtime

Answer (score 2):

People who are looking to do achieve same in docker instance being run by rancher, then they can play with docker-compose configuration. You need to add following lines in docker-compose file:

```
sysctls:
      net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_intvl: '45'
      net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_probes: '15'
      net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time: '120'
privileged: true
```

Once stack is created with docker-compose file containing above configuration, you can login to docker shell from Rancher and check corresponding configuration from /proc file system.